# Pagination in swiftUI doesn't loads next page

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview

I am trying to implement pagination in swiftUI, My deployment target is `iOS 13`
The complete example code is here https://github.com/janeshsutharios/Pagination_Example_swiftUI

Problem here i am facing is it doesn't loads up `page 2`(working Page 0 - 1)

I am using git API for pagination
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=swift&sort=stars&per_page=20&page=1

I am using `List` for pagination(if your answer is with `scrollView` with `forEach` also fines with me)
Logic for loading next page -

```
extension RandomAccessCollection where Self.Element: Identifiable {
    public func isLastItem<Item: Identifiable>(_ item: Item) -> Bool {
        guard !isEmpty else {
            return false
        }
        
        guard let itemIndex = firstIndex(where: { AnyHashable($0.id) == AnyHashable(item.id) }) else {
            return false
        }
        let distance = self.distance(from: itemIndex, to: endIndex)
        return distance == 1
    }
}
```

Loading next as -

```
private extension ContentView {
    func listItemAppears<Item: Identifiable>(_ item: Item) {
        if items.isLastItem(item) {
            isLoading = true
            // DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2) {
            page += 1
            loadData()
            //}
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does a guy named 'page' as in 'page += 1' come from?  'isLoading'?

Comment: I'm sure that's not how you update a variable in SwiftUI although I don't use it.